# python urlopen output wrong

Tags: python, urlopen

```
cj=http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener=build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
data={'uid' : uid , 'password' : password }   #uid is username to the website
data=urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
data=data.encode(encoding='utf-8')
url='http://202.117.120.37/xdjwWebNew/Servlet/UsersControl' # url is a link to a specific page
request=Request(url,data)
response=opener.open(request)
response.geturl()
```

it output:

```
'http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib'
```

I don't what's the problem.
Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What was the expected output? You asked for the url, and you got it. What's surprising about that?

Comment: @HenryKeiter  It's not this url. It should return the url required in 'request', not python.org.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for it to output? If you want the html page at the link, use `response.read()`. Via the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

```
This supports the following methods: read(), readline(), readlines()...
...these methods have the same interface as for file objects

The geturl() method returns the real URL of the page.
```

Comment: I added header information to the request. And it works properly. Is header information really necessary to a request?